# GitLab CI using MiKTeX docker image

Tags: miktex, automation, continuous-integration

I'm trying to set up a GitLab CI to compile my LaTeX file, but I would like to avoid having to download full TeXlive over and over again.
Afaik MiKTeX more or less will only download what is needed for the TeX file.

I already have a proper setup with the docker image blang/latex, but I can't seem to get miktex/miktex to compile.

It always fails with:

```
2018-06-21 09:40:38,858Z INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from geometry-de.tar.lzma...
2018-06-21 09:40:39,257Z FATAL pdflatex - The installed file does not exist.
2018-06-21 09:40:39,257Z FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="/miktex/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/geometry-de/geometry.sty"
2018-06-21 09:40:39,257Z FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/Core/Session/findfile.cpp
2018-06-21 09:40:39,257Z FATAL pdflatex - Line: 55
2018-06-21 09:40:39,258Z INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: miktex/miktex

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq inkscape python-pygments

build:
  script:
    - ./convert_svg.sh
    - pdflatex -shell-escape abgabe.tex
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*.pdf"
```

This is my project: https://gitlab.com/ZerataX/DS_TEMPLATE/

if there is some other tex distribution that is smaller, but also installs my dependencies automatically that would also be a great solution to my problem.

Comment: there's also a dockerized MiKTeX image: https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-docker

Comment: yes as I said in my question I am using the miktex/miktex image and I edited my question to include it in the yaml code block.

Comment: sorry, misunderstanding.

Comment: You could check the setup the latex teams uses https://github.com/latex3/latex2e.

Comment: thanks for that, but it seems like they manually state which packages they're going to use, which I would like to avoid: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/support/texlive.sh

Comment: Imho it is saner setup than on-the-fly in the middle of a pdflatex run and probably also faster (even more as texlive is cached).

Comment: why miktex can't you just apt-get texlive? for the L3 tests we need a bleeding edge setup as we are testing the latex development builds but for a normal document is that needed?

Comment: it seems nicer to only download the packages I need rather than the whole 5gb every time, but it's not a huge issue

Comment: You don't need texlive-full. Probably you'll be good to go with only a subset, so you're unlikely to really need 5 gb every time.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this which might help - https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/continuous-integration-of-latex-projects-with-gitlab-pages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that updating the locale db was required before on the fly installation of packages would work, so try this:

```
image: miktex/miktex

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq inkscape python-pygments

build:
  script:
    - mpm --update-db # <------------------------------------
    - ./convert_svg.sh
    - pdflatex -shell-escape abgabe.tex
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*.pdf"
```

See also

- Original issue: https://github.com/MiKTeX/docker-miktex/issues/21
- PR to describe gitlab CI in the README: https://github.com/MiKTeX/docker-miktex/pull/23
- Regarding caching (it is not currently possible on gitlab because the packages are not installed in the project dir): https://github.com/MiKTeX/docker-miktex/issues/22

Answer (score 1):

`geometry-de` doesn't contain `geometry.sty` (see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/29).

I would recommend that you update the package database: `mpm --update-db`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from stuck, there is an update because mpm is deprecated [MikTeX update CLI deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640055/miktex-update-cli-deprecated). Hence, use

```
miktex packages update-package-database
```