# MikTeX update CLI deprecated

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

I have a Task Scheduler in Windows 10 to update MikTeX weekly.

`mpm --update`

And now I get this warning:

```
Warning: --update: this option has been deprecated;
it will be removed from a future version of MiKTeX
```

Is any replacement for `--update`?

Comment: Try `miktex packages update` instead of `mpm --update`.

Comment: @hair-splitter Thanks a lot. Is working!

Comment: @hair-splitter Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @schtandard Thanks for saying it, I forgot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current version of MiKTeX, the `--update` option has been removed from the `mpm` (although still temporarily usable):
https://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html

This function has been taken over by the `update` command of miktex-packages program:
https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-packages.html

To update MiKTeX packages, you should use

> `miktex packages update`

instead of `mpm --update`.

Comment: Is there a variant of this command with miktex administrator privilege?

Comment: @Diaa Yes: `miktex --admin packages update`, see [here](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex.html)